# How can I choose a mysql table to insert data according to radio button? What's wrong in my jsp/java code?Why radio button don't work?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I have two tables in mysql database, one for student and one for teacher. Both tables have the same columns.

The code below inserts data only to the teacher's table. If user selects teacher's radio button, then the sign up data should be stored in teacher's table. If the user selects student's radio, then the sign up data should be stored in student's table.What's wrong in my jsp/jdbc code? What will be a solution for that?

What wrong in this query.Why this query insert data in a only student table of mysql not in teacher2 table. **either selected teacher/student radio button**

**radio but don't work**

```
String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
if (gender != null) {
String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";
// replace dots with your values
String query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";
st.executeUpdate(query);}
```

**PROBLEM IS HERE ALSO**

`st.executeUpdate(query);` // But data inserted in mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugn9B.jpg)

**index.jsp**

```
  <form  method="GET " action="statement2.jsp" autocomplete="on"> 
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="teacher" checked/> Teacher
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Student"/>Student
   <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
   <input type="button" onclick="location.href='reg.jsp';" value="Sign Up" />
  </form>
```

**statement2.jsp**

```
  <%
   String name=request.getParameter("first");
   String abc=request.getParameter("last");
   String cde=request.getParameter("user");
   String pass=request.getParameter("password");
   String confpass=request.getParameter("confirmpass");
   String emails=request.getParameter("email");
   String months=request.getParameter("month");
   String day=request.getParameter("day");
   String year=request.getParameter("year");

   String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
   if (gender != null) {
   String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";
// replace dots with your values
   String query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";
  st.executeUpdate(query);}     // problem is here

 %>
```

**reg.jsp** // registeration page for sign up

```
     <form  method="GET" action="statement2.jsp" autocomplete="on"> 
       <input id="firstnamesignup" name="first" required="required" type="text" placeholder="First" />
     <input id="lastnamesignup" name="last" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Last" />

     <select name="gender">
     <option value="male">Male</option>
     <option value="female">Female</option>
     </select>      
     </form>
```

---

**db conn.jsp**   //this file is for database connection

```
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
 Connection c1 = null;
 Statement st = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 c1 = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher","root", "abcde");

 {
  System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
  System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
  System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");

  st = (Statement) c1.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Statement Created Successfully");
  {
  System.out.println("We got an exception while creating a statement:" + "that probably means we're no longer connected.");
  }
  if (c1!= null) {
  System. out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
  } else {
  System.out.println("We should never get here.");
  }}

 %>
```

Comment: @Jens Where i'm wrong in my code?

Comment: I do not know. Use a Debugger to find it out

Comment: Do not tag your question with SQL-Server tag, if you use mysql. It is not the same

Comment: Is your table `teacher` or `teacher2`?

Comment: Is gender really `teacher`?

Comment: my table is teacher2 and <input type=" radio" name="gender"/>

Comment: @Jens problem is here `st.executeUpdate(query)`

Comment: Would you mind providing the error?

Comment: What you need to find the error (and so do we) is the error (exception) that you encounter. In your case, I guess this is the query. So check with a debugger or log the value of `query`. Since this depends on the gender value, see the value of this too. Give us the result please ;)

Comment: @AxelH Sql query is alright.

Comment: You means that your query is `INSERT INTO teacher2... ` but the insert is not done and you don't have any exception ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here was not on the query but rather on the parameter gender value the conditional operator you've coded `String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student"` was the one deciding on which table it should be inserted then you appends table variable together with its query, so my conclusion here is gender parameter was not returning "teacher" value which makes the table variable always "student". I suggest that you check first what parameter gender was returning.

Comment: i have added my all jsp file now check i think problem is here also `st.executeUpdate(query);` AND Here `<input type="radio" name="gender" value="teacher" checked/> Teacher
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Student"/>Student`